# create a ASMX web service in MVC with pfx certificate

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, web-config, pfx

I want to create a web service with c# in Visual Studio 2015 that require .pfx certificate to the client without https

I´m testing with my IIS  with autosigned certificated, but I cannot setup my web.config correctly

I was searching information but I cannot find any example that works.

Anyone know how to do it? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you create an ASMX within a MVC project? What is the purpose of this service?

Comment: the pourpose is only to ask for some datas. If you´re asking for why with this technology is because of the client. I was searching and maybe https is compulsory to use pfx certificate, what do you think?